# React.js. Is it better to create methods with parameters (and props will be arguments) or reference props in function body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arguments

Consider following examples:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Todos extends Component {

  renderList = (listArray) => { // our todos are function argument
    return listArray.map(listItem => (
      <li>listItem</li>
    ))
  };

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        renderList(todos);
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

Second example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Todos extends Component {

  renderList = () => { // but in this example we are explicitly reference to this.props 
    const { todos } = this.props;
    return todos.map(listItem => (
      <li>listItem</li>
    ))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        renderList();
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

I can never decide, which style is better. I tried searching it online, but it seems like a rare dilemna. So my questions is - Is it better to create methods with parameters (and props will be arguments) or reference props in function body? Is there any real difference? What is your preference?

Comment: I personally find the first example is more readable.

Comment: I prefer second options, what is cons to making a functions with arguments and passing a arguments, and handle a arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, I would always tend to pass the needed arguments to my methods instead of using the class scope most of all because of testability.
Let's say you want to test this method later, you can just pass the arguments you want and it's much easier and cleaner that way instead of having to set the right variables to your class (or whatever is the scope where your method is defined is).

That is to answer your question, but in the example you wrote above I would also consider creating a sub component to encapsulate your list item.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Anthony, thank you for the answer. I think easier testing is a good point and our methods are more likely to be pure. I would also consider creating new component in above case, but sometimes all I want is to create some specific css class depending on props - this is where it makes more sense to create a method. Thanks again!